# Kill all currently running cron jobs

Tags: bash, cron, command-line-interface, process, unix-shell

For some reason my cron job scripts aren't exiting cleanly and they're backing up my server. There are currently a couple hundred processes running for one of my users. I can use the following command to kill all processes by that user, but how can I simplify this to kill only crons?

```
pgrep -U username | while read id ; do kill -6 $id ; done
```

It would be dangerous to run the above command as is, correct? Wouldn't that kill mysql and other important things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To kill all processes for the user, you have a few options. I like:
`su - username` then `kill -9 -1`

To see which "cron" processes belong to user :

```
pgrep -u username cron
```

To kill those processes:

```
pkill -u username cron
```

Comment: I think this might work if I add an -f

Comment: Sure. Pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
kill -6 $(pgrep -U username cron)
```

You can search with pgrep full string with `-f` arg if you need to kill specific cron jobs, while let others live.

`kill` signal is pretty dangerous really, so you should check what you are going to kill. If username is 'root' then you can kill important things, yes.